# Upper bound for the k-th primorial to the power 1/k

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

For  $ n $ an integer greater than  $ 6 $ , let   $ Q(n)=\sqrt{2n}\#$.

Which upper bound in terms of  $ n $  can we get for  $ Q(n)^{\frac{1}{\pi(\sqrt{2n})}} $?

Comment: Why do you use $\sqrt{2n}$ instead of $n$?  It seems  curious

Comment: I need it for the application I have in mind.

Comment: See my question "About Goldbach's conjecture" on MO where  $ Q(n) $ is denoted by  $P_{ord_{C}(n)} $.

Comment: The PNT and the RH are exactly about estimating $\log (\prod_{p \le x} p)$ and $\pi(x)$.